# Infer new Document using Mahout 0.9 LDA

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, lda

I am able to build a LDA model using Mahout 0.9 CVB implementation. I now need to infer a new document using this model. 
I was wondering if there is any already existing method/implementation to do the same?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not yet a command line mahout algorithm for inferring a single new document with existing lda topic model. Fortunately there are some nice but not-so-well documented tools in mahout library.

I found [this blog post](http://jayaniwithanawasam.blogspot.fi/2013/12/infer-topics-for-documents-using-latent.html) that seems to have a working Java example.
Inferring should also be quite straight forward to implement with [CVB0DocInferenceMapper](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mrlegacy/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/lda/cvb/CVB0DocInferenceMapper.java).